# "Error: unexpected ',' in..." when running R code in .Rmd code chunks on Visual Studio Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

This is an example code snippet:

Problematic Code:

````
```{r}
ratings <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(rating) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    compound = mean(compound),
    neg = mean(neg),
    neu = mean(neu),
    pos = mean(pos),
  )

View(ratings)
```
````

This is the error I get:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsHAm.png)

```
r$> ratings <- df %>%
      dplyr::group_by(rating) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(
        compound = mean(compound),
        neg = mean(neg),
        neu = mean(neu),
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"    neu = mean(neu),
}"

r$>     pos = mean(pos)
      )
Error: unexpected ')' in:
"    pos = mean(pos)
  )"
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

I'm not exactly sure what's causing it. I'm on a Windows 11 system, using VSCode as the editor and Radian to run the code. For VSCode extensions I am using: R (REditorSuppor), Markdown All in One (Yu Zhang).

When I run the code on RStudio I do not get an error and the code runs as expected. I'd rather use VSCode and figure out the issue. When searching for an answer online, I've seen issues with unicode characters and actual extra punctuations causing errors. However, as far as I'm aware those don't seem to be the issue here, and how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: There is one more detail I forgot to mention above, the summarized function works if it is written as one line:

```
ratings <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(rating) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(compound = mean(compound), neg = mean(neg), neu = mean(neu), pos = mean(pos))
```

Comment: Your code is being split into two lines when you are passing it from the text editor to the console. Each of these lines is incomplete (unmatched opening bracket in the first, and unmatched closing bracket in the second). Also you seem to have a trailing comma in `dplyr::summarise()` though this should not cause an error.

Comment: Search for `}` in your code.  R is finding an extra one on the `neu = mean(neu)` line.  Maybe off to the right after a bunch of spaces?

Comment: @user2554330 There are no other } in the code or off to the right, I could write any multiline code and the issue would still appear.

Comment: Did you set `"r.bracketedPaste": true` in your settings.json?

Comment: @SamR That seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [`radian`](https://github.com/randy3k/radian) as your R terminal in VS Code you need to add the following to your user `settings.json`:

```r
"r.bracketedPaste": true
```

There are some other useful options in this [medium post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/a-fresh-start-for-r-in-vscode-ec61ed108cf6).

Instructions about how to access your `settings.json` are set out in the [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings), as well as further information about user and workspace settings.